# ¿Como puedo hacer un máximo de contador por grupos en android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una duda con respecto a un programa que estoy haciendo,en principio creo una configuración para que el usuario pueda elegir cuantos grupos quiere crear y cuantos jugadores por grupo,cuando lo crea le doy la posibilidad de empezar a insertar jugadores y elegir a que grupo quiere que vaya.Mi duda o mas bien mi pregunta es como puedo hacer un limitador por grupos,es decir, que cuando meta x jugadores en el grupo 1 y ese sea el máximo no pueda meter mas jugadores en el grupo 1 y que ocurra lo mismo con cuantos grupos tenga,he intentado hacer un arraylist para meter varios arraylist dentro de otros y intentar que funcione pero no lo consigo.En el spinner se muestra un arraylist con la cantidad de grupos que tengo en mi base de datos y los muestra en el spinner.Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A

Comment: Código de ejemplo. Qué tienes, algo. Así es complicado responder nada.

Comment: @AsieR_2 lo he actualizado con una foto del activity,lo que quiero hacer es que cuando escoga en el spinner a que grupo pertenece,tenga un contador de cuantas personas puede meter en ese grupo,esos datos los recogo en un metodo que recoge los campos de la tabla que son cantidad de grupos y cantidad de jugadores

Comment: ¿Y no tienes una base de datos para eso?

Comment: Pon una variable MAX_JUGADORES. Cuando cargas el spinner saca también el numero de jugadores por grupo. Antes de insertar comprueba si los jugadores del grupo no superan el máximo. Como dice Asier así es difícil...

Comment: Tengo una base de datos sqlite y tengo una tabla configuracion que contiene un integer de numero de jugadores y numero de grupos y eso los saco en la actividad de jugadores para mostrar todos los grupos que existen en el spinner.

Comment: Pues ya está - si el numero de jugadores en el grupo supera el máximo simplemente no metas el grupo en el spinner

Comment: No es eso,haber si me explico bien,yo lo que intento hacer es que muestro la cantidad de grupos que existen y lo que quiero es que si hay una cantidad maxima de 4 jugadores por grupo,si al meter un 5 jugador en el grupo 1 ,que le diga que no pueda porque ha sobrepasado el limite

Comment: Vale. A ver, cuando intentas meter otro jugador, si supera 4 - muestra el mensaje

Comment: Exacto,pero mi complicación es que si tengo varios grupos,como hacer para que si escoge el grupo x le haga un conteo de cada vez que inserte un jugador,para así si escoge el grupo 1 y llevaba ya 4 jugadores insertados no pueda meter un 5 o si escoge el grupo 2 y lleva 3 jugadores insertados, pueda insertar otro mas

Comment: @manu96 Añade en la tabla de grupos un campo límite y otro con la cantidad o un único campo de restantes.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta algo así:

```
public class TuAction {

    private static final int MAX = 4;

    // esto lo puedes hacer por nombre o por índice (el caso)
    private Map<Integer, Integer> jugadoresPorGrupo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // sacar los grupos de BD
        List<Grupo> grupos = null;// haz lo que se debe hacer

        // sacar numero de jugadores ya insertados por cada grupo
        // o tenerlo en el objeto Grupo
        // o cualquier otra cosa que te diga cuantos jugadores hay en el grupo
        jugadoresPorGrupo = null;// metelos aqui por cada grupo

        // rellenar el spinner
    }

    public void enviarDatos(View v) {
        // recupera los datos del jugador, grupo incluido
        int indiceGrupo;
        // saca el numero de jugadores de jugadoresPorGrupo según el grupo que has recuperado de la vista
        int numJugadores = jugadoresPorGrupo.get(indiceGrupo);
        // compara con MAX
        if (numJugadores >= MAX) {
            // mostrar mensaje
        }
        else {
            // insert en BD
        }
    }

}
```

Espero no haberme equivocado mucho y que te sirva

Comment: gracias por la ayuda,al final he conseguido hacerlo de otra forma que ha sido llamando a la base de datos y haciendo un conteo de si la cantidad de personas que existen en un mismo grupo es mayor al permitido muestre un mensaje.Gracias de todas formas a todos

Comment: Si lo realizaste de otra forma ¿Porque marcaste esta publicación como solución? @manu96

Comment: Al final es lo mismo - en mi comentario *sacar numero de jugadores ya insertados por cada grupo*, así que el número de jugadores se saca de BD  y se compara. @Elenasys, no te enfades, no veo como est ote afecta a ti. Además no ha aceptado la respuesta.